# How to remove (All) from crosstalk's filter_select in R?

Tags: r, plotly, r-plotly, crosstalk

I was following Figure 16.7's example from https://plotly-r.com/client-side-linking.html and cannot figure out why there is a selection called "(All)" or how to remove it.

[image: Image of what it looks like here]

Code I was using is below

```
library(plotly)
library(crosstalk)
data(txhousing, package = "ggplot2")
tx <- highlight_key(txhousing)
gg <- ggplot(tx) + geom_line(aes(date, median, group = city))
filter <- bscols(
  filter_select("id", "Select a city", tx, ~city),
  ggplotly(gg, dynamicTicks = TRUE),
  widths = c(12, 12)
)
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: All doesn't show up when I run the code. Also your widths are should add up to 12, so maybe use `c(6,6)`. It gave me an error using `c(12,12)`.

Comment: @william3031 That's interesting. Despite changing the widths, I am still getting the (All) selection. Do you know which version of crosstalk you are using?

Comment: Hi, these versions: crosstalk_1.1.1 plotly_4.9.2.1  ggplot2_3.3.5

Comment: @william3031 Installing version 1.1.1 of crosstalk fixed the error, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

This javascript works for Crosstalk 1.2.0 on a leaflet map:

```javascript
function remove_all_option() {
    document.getElementById("Your ID Here").getElementsByClassName("selectized")[0].selectize.removeOption("");
}
    
window.onload = remove_all_option;
```