# How to remove (all) option in filter_select function from plotly package?

Tags: r, plotly, crosstalk

I want to remove the (All) option from the plotly's filter_select function since it makes all the data from each filter options show up as the default in a way that doesn't make sense (see pic). If I can't remove the (All) option, is there a way to specify which of my filter options I'd like to display as the default?

Seems very similar to this question, but my package versions are more recent (crosstalk 1.2.0, ggplot2 3.4.0, plotly 4.10.1) [How to remove (All) from crosstalk's filter_select in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70687190/how-to-remove-all-from-crosstalks-filter-select-in-r)

Thanks so much!

```
trends_age_subplot <- subplot(plotly_trends_age_pctpos %>% layout(height=600),
                              style(plotly_trends_age_case, showlegend=F),
                              style(plotly_trends_age_test, showlegend=F),
                              nrows=3, shareX=TRUE, titleY=TRUE, which_layout=1)
```

```
trends_age_final <- bscols(widths=c(2,10),
                           list(filter_select(id='tr_boro', label='Borough', sharedData=shared_trends_age, group=~boro, multiple=F)),
                           trends_age_subplot)
```

[Pic of how data is presented when (All) is selected as default](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q9Qtn.png)